# missing ; before statement jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error that I don't understand:

```
`missing ; before statement`
```

Here is the code

```
        },
        'addevent' : function(data, formData){
            var entry = fx.deserialize(formData); 
        }, 
        'deserialize' : function(str){
            var data = str.split("&"),

            pairs = [], entry{}, key, val; //ERROR
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax

`entry{}`

doesn't look right to me.

Do you want

`entry={},`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have it in one line:</strike>

```
var data = str.split("&"), pairs = [], entry{}, key, val;
```

You are missing `=` sign, should be:

```
..., entry = {}, ...
```

Comment: Whitespace is of no importance, single or multiline is the same

Comment: @Andreas my bad, tested only after posting. Fixed now.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: as this is now a valid answer, i removed downvote.

Answer (score -1):

```
},
        'addevent' : function(data, formData){
            var entry = fx.deserialize(formData); 
        }, 
        'deserialize' : function(str){
            var data = str.split("&");

            pairs = [];
            entry = {key, val};
```

Comment: -, now getting `SyntaxError: invalid object initializer`

Comment: What are you wanting to do with key and val? I think your solution would lie in what you're trying to achieve.

As in, data would be the deserialized data - and so storing the data in pairs? And thus pairs[i] = data with i being a loop count?

Answer (score -2):

```
        var data = str.split("&"), <====== Here should be ';'

        !var! pairs = [], entry{}, key, val; //ERROR // var should be again
```